# Azure Devops Pipeline Making Changes in Web.config file

Tags: iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, config

When I run my azure pipeline it runs successfully but during the build process it adds environment variables to the web.config file. I want to avoid that, it is causing some trouble.

```
task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
displayName: 'Publish NET Project' inputs:
command: 'publish' publishWebProjects: false
projects: ${{ parameters.projectsPath }}
arguments: '-configuration ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }} --output
$Build. ArtifactStagingDirectory)' zipAfterPublish: true
```

Web config file

```
<environmentVariables>
<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value-"some value" />
<environmentVariables>
```

I think there is a problem above in publish part. I want the file to be included in publish folder just not transform/add variables to file. Please help